# Angular2 - Check-All box is selecting disabled inputs

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple component where there is a table that contains a `CheckAll` checkbox and then each table row contains a checkbox for that individual row.

There are some pieces of criteria that will disable a row from being selected and this is reflected using the `[disabled]` directive on the specific rows.

This disables the individual row just fine, however, my `check all` box is still selecting these disabled `rows`.

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-condensed" *ngIf="importResults?.length > 0">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th><input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" [(ngModel)]="checkedAll" (ngModelChange)="toggleAllEmployees($event)"></th>
               <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let i of importResults" >
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox"
                            id="checkbox_{{ i.QID }}"
                            [checked]="i.checked"
                            (click)="toggleSelectedEmployee(i)"
                            [(ngModel)]="i.checked" 
                            [disabled] = "i.OnTempAssignment == 'True'"
                            />
                </td>
                <td>{{ i.PreferredName }} {{ i.LastName }}</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
```

**Component:**

```
    /**
     * Toggle all employees (checked/unchecked) in step 2.
     *
     * @param {any} flag
     * @memberof EmployeeSelectionComponent
     */
    toggleAllEmployees(flag) {
        if (flag) {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.importResults.length; i++) {
                    this.importResults[i].checked = true;
            }
            this.employeeSelection = this.importResults;
            // Emit our changes
            this.selectedEmployees.emit(this.employeeSelection);
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.importResults.length; i++) {
                this.importResults[i].checked = false;
                this.employeeSelection = [];
                // Emit our changes
                this.selectedEmployees.emit(this.employeeSelection);
            }
        }
    }
```

**My Question:**

How can I make this `check all` checkbox ignore (not check) any checkboxes that are disabled?

Comment: can you recreate a plunker for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled might prevent the user from changing the status of the checkbox, but you are changing the underlying model in code.  You need to check in the code that sets the value for each item if you want to allow it...

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.importResults.length; i++) {
        if (this.importResults[i].OnTempAssignment !== 'True') {
            this.importResults[i].checked = true;
        }
}
```

Also, you are calling your method with an event: `toggleAllEmployees($event)`, not a flag.  This will always be a truthy value, right?  I think you need to check the value of 'checkedAll' or `$event.target.value` instead of the `flag` parameter.

Comment: Thanks - This answer worked for me. Regarding the `$event` statement though.. I used a snippet I found online to get this working. However, when I log `$event` in my function, all it returns is `true/false` so I assume it has something to do with how the binding is set up where its working via the `flag` bool?

Comment: Ah, I see the event is `ngModelChange` which just provides the new value as $event...